# How to create objects having attributes from differents java class

Tags: java, architecture

I have a class Creature with another class Flying and Undead that extends Creature. How could I create a object that have both the Flying and Undead attributes?

```
class Creature(){
String name;
public Creature(String name){
    this.name=name;
}
class Flying extends Creature{
    ...
}
class Undead extends Creature{
    ...
}

Object creature = new Object();//Both Flying and Undead
```

Is there another way to do it or should I use a different approach?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: No, I want to implements a "Creature" system for a game. We can create a "Human", "Zombie", "Flying" creatures, like MTG cards type line (You can have multiples types for one card). So a creature can be "Flying" and "Human" (like an angel). The questions is about how to create such creature than can share attributes from the human and the flying.

Comment: Sounds like a [mixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you can not have a class that is inherited from more than one super class. you better use Interfaces, because you can use more many implemented Interfaces.
Interfaces are objects similar to classes. in Interfaces you can have variables and and methods, nut defining and giving values to methods and variables should be done in the class that implemented the Interfaces.
For example :

```
     Interface MyInterface 
          {
             int myVar;
             void myMethod (int var);
          }

    class MyClass implements MyInterface // with comma(,) you can separate multiple interfaces
 {
    void myMethod (int var) {//do something}
    int myVar = 1;
    }
```

with Interfaces named *Flying* and *Undead* or *Creature* maybe you can do what you want.

[here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm) you can learn more about Interfaces.